# Get position by yaw and pitch of three (or more) known point coordinates

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a solution finding a position based on yaw and pitch of 3 known position.
The problem is I don't know what to search in google as I don't know the correct term or keyword for this, I'm sure it has been answered somewhere, so a pointer to that solution is very welcome.

Below are the problems:

```
Known: 
Yaw(a) and Pitch(b) angle from point F to 3 known points
F to P1 = {a1,b1}
F to P2 = {a2,b2}
F to P3 = {a3,b3}

Coordinate of three point
P1 = {x1,y2,z1}
P2 = {x2,y2,z2}
P3 = {x3,y3,z3}
```

What is the coordinate of point F?

Comment: A kind of geodetic triangulation (surveying, trilateration)

Answer (score 0):

For each Pi one gets a line on which F should lie:

```
(fx,fy,fz) = (xi,yi,zi) + ti * (cos ai cos bi, sin ai cos bi, sin bi)
```

Because of measurement and rounding errors the three lines will in general not meet in one point. But one can look for the point with the minimal sum of the squared distances to each line (see e.g. [Finding the intersection point of many lines in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/finding-the-intersection-point-of-many-lines-in-3d-point-closest-to-all-lines))

Comment: hi thank you for answeing this, what is ti in your equation is ?

Comment: `t1`, `t2`, `t3` are the free parameters of the parametrizations of the lines defined by the points `P1`, `P2`,`P3` and the angles at which point `F` is seen

Comment: The methods for computing `F` in the referenced question do not need the variables `t1`,`t2`,`t3`. The methods described there just use the defining point and vector for each line. (The notation `F = P + t*v` just means that point `F` is on the line defined by the point `P` and the vector `v`.)